# How can I use System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.Polling?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I downloaded **System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.Polling** from [this link](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-corefxlab/package/nuget/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.Polling/0.1.0-e160210-1).

This library comes from [corefxlab github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab).

Can anyone show me a sample that how this library works ?

I installed it but after set constructor parametters and calling start() I dont find any event or ... !!!

Can anyone help me to use it ?!

```
 PollingWatcher p = new PollingWatcher(@"...path...", true, 10);
 p.Start();
 ??????? // How trace activities ?!?!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[Fact]
public static void FileSystemWatcher_Created_File()
{
    var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var watcher = new PollingWatcher(currentDir, false, 100);
    watcher.ChangedDetailed += (changes) =>
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, changes.Length);
        var change = changes[0];
        Assert.Equal(ChangeType.Created, change.ChangeType);
        Assert.Equal(fileName, change.Name);
        Assert.Equal(currentDir, change.Directory);
    };
    watcher.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    using (var file = new TemporaryTestFile(fileName))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        watcher.Dispose();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}

[Fact]
public static void FileSystemWatcher_Deleted_File() 
{
    var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var watcher = new PollingWatcher(currentDir, false, 100);

    using (var file = new TemporaryTestFile(fileName))
    {
        watcher.ChangedDetailed += (changes) =>
        {
            Assert.Equal(1, changes.Length);
            var change = changes[0];
            Assert.Equal((byte)ChangeType.Deleted, (byte)change.ChangeType);
            Assert.Equal(fileName, change.Name);
            Assert.Equal(currentDir, change.Directory);
        };
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        watcher.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(200);
    watcher.Dispose();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}

[Fact]
public static void FileSystemWatcher_Changed_File() 
{
    var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var watcher = new PollingWatcher(currentDir, false, 100);

    using (var file = new TemporaryTestFile(fileName))
    {
        watcher.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        watcher.ChangedDetailed += (changes) =>
        {
            Assert.Equal(1, changes.Length);
            var change = changes[0];
            Assert.Equal(ChangeType.Changed, change.ChangeType);
            Assert.Equal(fileName, change.Name);
            Assert.Equal(currentDir, change.Directory);
        };
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        file.WriteByte(100);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        watcher.Dispose();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

The above code is taken from the unit tests on that git repo.